# PHP post $_GET variable in table field

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some problems trying to post $_GET variables into a table.

Here is my script:

```
include 'connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['client_name'])) {

$_GET['list']; //these are variables passed through from another page and I want these to post in the same table this page is suppose to post in.
$_GET['list_id'];


$Cname = $_POST['client_name'];
$Cnumber = $_POST['client_number'];
$listid = $_POST['list_id'];
$listname = $_POST['list'];


if(!empty($Cname) && !empty($Cnumber)){

    $query = "INSERT INTO clients (id, client_name, client_number, list_name, date_registered, list_id) VALUES ('$userid','$Cname', '$Cnumber', '$listname', now(), '$listid')";

    mysql_query($query);

echo '<br />
 <br />
        You successfully added a new clients to your list <a href="http://somewebsite.com/clients.php">View Update</a>';


    mysql_close();
    } 

    else {

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Both fields are required");</script>';
        }
```

Whenever I run the script everything else but the listname and list_id is posted in the database table. 
I tried assigning the get variables to new variable such as

$listNAME = $_GET['id'];

but even with that I still end up with empty fields in my table

I even tried to use the $_GET variable in the mysql INSERT query and still no luck

Can anyone help me out and give me some advice as to what I can do to solve the empty fields when the script runs.

```
<form action="addclient.php" method="POST">

Name of Client: <input type="text" name="client_name">

Client's Number: <input type="text" name="client_number" placeholder="1-876-xxx-xxx">

 <input type="submit" >


</form>
```

Comment: when you print out the get variable what do you see?

Comment: @MrD I see the info from the variables passed in the URL

Comment: your columns are set to the proper data type? varchar or text or>>?

Comment: @SmithSmithy for the columns I want the variables to post in, list_name and list_id. They're varchar(100) and int(11)

Comment: Why you are mixing $_POST and $_GET request. You are saying `ending up with empty fields.` How could that happen when you testing `if(!empty($Cname) && !empty($Cnumber)){` So your fields `$Cname` and `$Cnumber`can not be emtpy.

Comment: @moskito-x I'm ending up with empty list_name and list_id fields.

Comment: Where you setting `list_name` and `list_id fields` ? If you do it with a <form> and a submit your `method` mustbe `method="post"` . As long we cannot see your <form> we can't see what's going on.

Comment: @moskito-x I added the html form

Comment: and where is your submit ?

Comment: @moskito-x sorry about that, there it is

Comment: I can not see where you set `listid` and `list` . So where should they come from ?

Comment: @moskito-x listid and list are coming from another page. Once this link is clicked these variables are passed in the url

"<a href=\"addclient.php?list_id=$listid&list='$listname'\">Add New Client</a>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say it only to notice .

**Please use PDO or mysqli**

---

if you are calling your addclient.php like

```
http://localhost/addclient.php?list_id=100&list=mylistname
```

than you must catch both variables in addclient.php

```
if (isset($_GET['list_id'])) {

 $listid = $_GET['list_id'];
 $listname = $_GET['list'];

}
```

and your form

```
<form action="addclient.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="$listid">
    <input type="hidden" name="list" value="$listname">
Name of Client: <input type="text" name="client_name">
Client's Number: <input type="text" name="client_number" placeholder="1-876-xxx-xxx">
 <input type="submit" >
</form>
```

and after submit

```
if(isset($_POST['client_name'])) {

$Cname = $_POST['client_name'];
$Cnumber = $_POST['client_number'];
$listid = $_POST['list_id'];
$listname = $_POST['list'];
....
}
```

and in your insert

```
VALUES ('$userid','$Cname', '$Cnumber', '$listname', now(), '$listid')
```

$listid without quotes it's a `int(11)` .

```
VALUES ('$userid','$Cname', '$Cnumber', '$listname', now(), $listid)
```

Comment: thank you @moskito-x I used this and managed to make everything work

Answer (score 4):

You say you have $_GET variables, but you are trying to retrieve them as $_POST variables:

```
$listid = $_POST['list_id'];
$listname = $_POST['list'];
```

Isn't it the issue? You could also try this to see what's comming in both arrays:

```
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
```

Alternatively, you could use $_REQUEST as it receives either $_GET or $_POST variables.